# as3 array tostring to textfiled line by line

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I want to print the array elements into the text field for the line-by-line.
I tried but failed,

```
bulunanliste.text = secilenkelime.toString("\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Array' [`join()`](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#join%28%29) method:

```
bulunanliste.text = secilenkelime.join("\n");
```